# MATLAB command for pole zero plot of continuous time system(s-domain)?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

Documentation of MATLAB command "zplane" mentions that it is used for plotting pole zero plot of discrete time system. But there is no mention about any command which may be used for plotting pole zero plot of continuous time systems

Comment: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/lti.pzmap.html ? I think its also because conitnous systems are analysed in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

Hello！You can use `pzmap` or `pzplot` in `Control System Toolbox™`. Read the documentation for more information.